# changing non-partition table to partition table in hive without mentioning all the columns

Tags: hive, ddl

Hi my table has 150 columns and i dont want to mention the column name while doing partition. Is there any way using temp table to create partitioned table from non partitioned one.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary table in Hive doesn't support Partitioning.
 You cannot create any permanent partitioned table without mentioning Partition 
 Column.